# How to install a library from GitHub to QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt, github

I am in a little over my head.

I am trying to write a c++ GUI program in QT Creator and using Windows 10.

I need the following library: https://github.com/rahulsinghk998/libtmcl

The install instructions are all based on linux. I am new to all this.

How can I 'install' or use this package in QT Creator?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's very small lib. I think you can just "add new subproject -> c++ lib" and put to subproj folder all .h and .cpp file. Futher in main project click "add lib -> internal lib"